# bootstrap model is not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, conflict

I am using Bootstrap 'modal' in my page with jquery 1.8.3. It is properly working until i make an ajax call from the modal. After the ajax call, if i try to open the modal popup again, i am getting an error like **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'modal'**.

I found the problem with the server content which comes through ajax. the content has some older jquery version (V 1.2.6), So if i remove the jquery file, modal is properly working. But i am not suppose to remove it from that page.

kindly suggest me to resolve this.

Comment: Are you pulling in an html page with your ajax call? The reason the modal is not working is because there is a javascript error which will stop all other javascript on the page from working.

Answer (score 0):

Because your older jQuery overwrites your jQuery (so the jQuery object is reconstructed). To avoid this, make your pulling content to pure string instead of a script.